# How to get value inside XML tag?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have the follow XML structure:

```
<Document>
  <Sectors>
    <Sector>
      SectorName1
      <Subsectors>
        <Subsector>Subsector1</Subsector> 
        <Subsector>Subsector2</Subsector> 
      </Subsectors>
    </Sector>
    <Sector>
      SectorName2
      <Subsectors>
        <Subsector>Subsector1</Subsector> 
        <Subsector>Subsector2</Subsector> 
      </Subsectors>
    </Sector>
  </Sectors>  
</Document>
```

Also I have classes for deserialize:

```
    public class MetaDataXML
    {
        public class SectorXML
        {
            [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Sector")]
            string SectorName { get; set; }

            [XmlArray]
            [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Subsector")]
            public List<string> Subsectors { get; set; }
        }

        public List<SectorXML> Sectors { get; set; }
    }
```

And part of code which do deserialize:

```
var xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "Document", IsNullable = true };
var reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MetaDataXML), xRoot);
var data = (MetaDataXML)reader.Deserialize(streamXML);
```

After deserialization I successfully get subsectors velues, but I didn't get values for SectorName. How I need to organize my structure of class that I'll get values "SectorName1" and "SectorName2" for my string SectorName property?

---

I found that that this case it's a "Mixed Content". How we can parse this text values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I am not entirely sure what it is you're trying to achieve here, I've made a few modifications to your XML class and provided some sample code below that is able to retrieve all of the information about a sector, including its name and the name of all the subsectors inside it.

XML Class:

```
namespace DocumentXml
{
    [XmlRoot("Document")]
    public class Document
    {
        [XmlArray("Sectors")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Sector")]
        public Sector[] Sectors { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Sector")]
    public class Sector
    {
        [XmlAttribute("SectorName")]
        public string SectorName { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("Subsectors")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Subsector")]
        public string[] Subsectors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Main Program Class:

```
namespace DocumentXml
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = @"D:\sandbox\DocumentXml\DocumentXml\Sample.xml";
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));
            var document = serializer.Deserialize(File.OpenRead(path)) as Document;
            var sectors = document.Sectors;
            foreach (var s in sectors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Sector Name: {s.SectorName}");
                foreach (var ss in s.Subsectors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Subsector Name: {ss}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample XML:

```
<Document>
  <Sectors>
    <Sector SectorName="SectorName1">
      <Subsectors>
        <Subsector>Subsector1</Subsector>
        <Subsector>Subsector2</Subsector>
      </Subsectors>
    </Sector>
    <Sector SectorName="SectorName2">
      <Subsectors>
        <Subsector>Subsector1</Subsector>
        <Subsector>Subsector2</Subsector>
      </Subsectors>
    </Sector>
   </Sectors>
</Document>
```

Output:

[image: Console Output]

---

**EDIT**

Since the XML structure cannot be changed, this new class will preserve the structure and also allow you to get the value in question. `XmlText` returns everything inside the value so a custom set had to be used to ensure that the whitespace was correctly trimmed from it.

```
[XmlRoot("Document")]
public class MetaDataXml
{
    [XmlArray("Sectors")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Sector")]
    public Sector[] Sectors { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Sector")]
public class Sector
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    private string _sectorName;

    [XmlText]
    public string SectorName
    {
        get
        {
            return _sectorName;
        }
        set
        {
            _sectorName = value.Trim();
        }
    }

    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Subsector")]
    public List<string> Subsectors { get; set; }
}
```

Sample Program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = @"D:\sandbox\DocumentXml\DocumentXml\Sample.xml";

        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MetaDataXml));
            var data = (MetaDataXml)deserializer.Deserialize(stream);
            foreach (var s in data.Sectors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Sector Name: {s.SectorName}");
                foreach (var ss in s.Subsectors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Subsector Name: {ss}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to get it without XML modifications.

Comment: @A.Bruilo I've modified my post above, it maintains your XML structure, but your class needs some reworking. In an ideal world. this sector name should be an XML Attribute.